# Can I use libVLCSharp to render video frames into memory?

Tags: xamarin.android, libvlcsharp

Is it possible to render video into memory in real time and take frames when I need them? Can Hardware acceleration be used in this case?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes, you can with the Video Callbacks API.
See the thumbnailer example here that is using this technique : https://code.videolan.org/mfkl/libvlcsharp-samples/tree/master/PreviewThumbnailExtractor

As for the second question, no, the output needs to be copied into RAM, which obviously kills performance since you're not using hardware acceleration from end to end.

That's at least the API state of libvlc 3, but things might change in libvlc 4.